# Numeric date changed to String

Tags: python, string, date

I need help creating a function that takes a user input(Numeric Date) and turns it into a string 
For Example:
 input: 2018-06-20
 output: June 20th 2018
any hints or code would help me out. Thank you

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: https://www.guru99.com/date-time-and-datetime-classes-in-python.html

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
d = '2018-06-20'
datetime.datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%B %d %Y')
```

Output:

```
June 20 2018
```

For more formatting you can look [here](http://strftime.org/)